# Why doesn't my while loop continue when it isn't true?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Im trying to get the user to input either a or v and if they input something other than that it runs a while loop until they correct it. However if I input b for example the program just ends and doesn't play the condition when it's false.

I've when through many iterations of the code but this is my latest version. It breaks the loop if true and should carry out the else statement. I've tried it without if statements and a elif statement instead of else.

Code:

```
money = 0

open = input('Add or view a / v :')

while open != 'a' or 'v':
    if open == 'a' or 'v' :
        break
    else:   
        print('Please input a or v')
        print(' ')
        open = input('Add or view a / v :')
```

Comment: Side note: don't use `open` as a variable name - that shadows the builtin `open`